# how the url of the image is known while using paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, paperclip

I tried PaperClipExample and it is working fine. I use s3 to store images. And i want to know how the images are displayed. To say exactly, i have

```
pic_file_name
pic_content_type
pic_file_size
pic_updated_at
```

in the user model. I do not have url of the pic, then how can i able to get the images using

`<%= image_tag @user.pic.url %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following link may help you.
[Upload image using paperclip gem.](https://gkunwar1.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/how-to-upload-file-using-paperclip-in-rails/)

in your show action of controller add: `@user = User.find(params[:id])`  if your Model is User. general syntax is: `@user = Model.find(params[:id])`

Comment: what i need is, in show.html.erb we have mentioned <%= image_tag @user.pic.url %> where is the url residing?

Comment: ok but i have in my model                                                            "name"
     "email"
     "created_at"
     "updated_at"
     "attach_file_name"
     "attach_content_type"
     "attach_file_size"
     "attach_updated_at"
     "pic_file_name"
     "pic_content_type"
     "pic_file_size"
     "pic_updated_at" but where is url specified

Comment: paperclip gem itself specify the url

Comment: ok. That is what i wanted to know. And one more thing, when i right click on the image and copy the image address then it can be used by any others. So is there is any way such that others cannot use it?